# How to install BuDDy lib in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm trying to install [BuDDy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/buddy/) on Windows using Cygwin. I found [these instructions](https://github.com/fd00/yacp/tree/master/buddy) but I'm having problems with installing `libbdd0-2.4-1bl4` requirement. Also, when running `cygport ./buddy-2.4-X.cygport all` from the manual above, I'm getting this error:

```
>>> buddy requires:
>>> libbdd0 requires: cygwin libgcc1 libstdc++6
>>> libbdd-devel requires: libbdd0
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error.
You build the buddy package and libbdd0 is a sub package of buddy. 
Looks on the `buddy-*/dist` directory

To install the package the easy way is to build your own local repository and install buddy from it. genini will help you to create the local `setup.ini`

https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-apps/genini.git;a=summary

```
genini --help
Usage: genini [--okmissing=key ...] [--recursive] [--output=file] [--help] [setup.ini] [dir ...]
Create cygwin setup.ini from setup.ini, setup.hint and tar ball information.

    --okmissing=key    don't warn if key is missing from setup.ini or setup.hint
                       or if some expected `source' or `install' tarballs are
                       missing. Option may be repeated. --okmissing=install is
                       useful if hint files contain `prev' or `test' entries for
                       missing tarballs. --okmissing=source is useful for
                       LOCAL-ONLY[*] srcless install media.
    --recursive        recurse all subdirectories of specified dirs
    --output=file      output setup.ini info to file
    --help             display this message

[*] You wouldn't want to violate the GPL, now would you?

Report bugs to cygwin mailing list.
```

**How to build a local site:**

Create a directory `http%3a%2f%2fYOURSITENAME%2f` to simulate a local copy of a web site.
Create sub dirs for the chosen architectory `noarch` `x86` `x86_64`.
Recursive copy `buddy-2.4-1bl4-ARCH/dist/buddy` in the chosen arch directory eg `x86_64\buddy`.

Build the local setup

```
genini --recursive noarch x86_64 > x86_64/setup.ini
```

At this point you can use `setup-x86_64.exe` with option `-X` to install from the local copy.
Also `setup-x86_64.exe` has a `--help` option to report all the available options.

Comment: I've never used genini before and there is not README file in the repo I cloned from the link you provided. Could you please give me more details on how to install BuDDy using genini?

Comment: I honestly feel a bit like an idiot because after two days of trying, I cannot manage to apply your proposition of a solution. Every tar of BuDDy I downloaded doesn't have a setup file and hence I could not use genini in order to install it. If it's not too much trouble, I would appreciate if you try installing it BuDDy to your device and share the process with me. I found another solution which I will post in a separate answer but will mark it once I get everything running (other errors emerged after installation of buddy).

Comment: I built and uploaded the package on http://matzeri.altervista.org/x86_64/buddy/ . Instruction for installation are on the main page http://matzeri.altervista.org/

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After three days of trying, I bumped into this [BuDDy archive](http://Download%20BuDDy%20tar%20from%20http://buddy.sourcearchive.com/downloads/2.4-8/buddy_2.4.orig.tar.gz) from where I downloaded tar and simply doing the following:

```
tar -zxvf buddy_2.4.orig.tar.gz
cd buddy-2.4
./configure
make
make install
```

BuDDy is now installed but it is not found by my program in the linking process so I will mark this answer as the correct one once I get everything working.